# Angular library dependency injection @inject @host

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have project with library where in  one of the classes I want to provide service thru @optional @host and @inject decorator by injection token. In parent component I could provide or not this class in providers array. When I refer to the library as to source ts code everything is working but when I refer to it in the dist folder builded variant my provided service is null. Angular 8. If it helps.

Comment: So when I used string instead injection token it actually worked.... Don't know exactly why. May be because there are 2 calls yo new Injection token and they are not equal

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the dist folder and running

```
ng build
```

Comment: Does not help. Now I'm trying forward ref